# Is there a way to show last month top questions for a tag?

Tags: support, tag-search, top-questions

I can get the month's top questions on a page like this: https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

Or the top questions of all time tagged 'C' here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c

Can I combine them? I want the top questions tagged 'C' from the last month or week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use search parameters for this: `is:q [c] created:30d..` gets the questions tagged [c] that were asked within the last 30 days. Sort them by votes, and there you have it:  [Top C questions of the last 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bc%5d%20created%3a30d..%20), a link suitable for bookmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use the following links to get the 'C' tag's hot questions for the last week or month.

For Week: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/hot?filter=week

For Month: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/hot?filter=month

---

**Step by step to get the result:**

- Search any tag from the [Tags menu](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) then from the result select your desired tag, in the result panel click the **top users** link

[image: Top Users link]

- In the **Tag Info** page, select the **hot** tab, then you can filter the hot questions for the week or month.

[image: Hot questions of a tab]

Comment: Thanks! my only complaint is that it lists hot answers rather than hot questions. Which is almost the same thing, so it works well enough.